# Iterating through xlsx column of strings to compare and match in python

Tags: python, for-loop, xlsx

I'm struggling to read two columns in an excel file and operate on them in python.

I can do it fine individually with various methods (df.at, and using hard coded indexes), but am seriously struggling to do it with a loop.

Here is my data:
first_name  last_name
William      Dixon
Fiona        trust
Fred         Nicholson
Teddy        Blackmore
Erica        Frank
Pauline      Strauss
John         Dobson
Sarah        Timmings

The code I'm using is as follows

```
import xlrd  # install xlrd from  http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dataset1_path = "Mock Data/Mock data 1.xlsx"


df1 = pd.read_excel(dataset1_path,
                        columns = ["first_name","last_name", "DOB", "partner", "business_name", "full_name"])
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    temp_first_name = row['first_name']
    temp_last_name = row['last_name']
    full_name = temp_firstname + " " + temp_lastname
    print(full_name)
```

It builds, but does not print the concatenated list of the first and last names. I get some pretty weird results, including the creation of a new column with integers in my xlsx file.

Comment: Can you please give us a couple examples of what is printed? Also, can you print the temp_first_name and the first_last_name as well to show us what you get?

Comment: Don't use `.iterrows()`. Loops should be avoided when working with Pandas, and `.iterrows()` is particularly bad. Also, is there any reason you're using xlrd? The library is unmaintained and they themselves suggest only using it to handle old .xls files. The description of the project's github repo is literally "Please use openpyxl where you can..."

Comment: On top of what @MatthewKligerman, some data would be nice. Please see: [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `zip`:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'first_name':['Jim', 'Jack', 'Janet'], 'last_name':['Smith', 'Wilson', 'Jackson']})
for first, last in zip(df1.first_name, df1.last_name):
    full_name = first + " " + last
    print(full_name)
```

outputs:

```
Jim Smith
Jack Wilson
Janet Jackson
```

I assume this is for practice, but iterating like this is not an efficient way to use a dataframe. This is a bit more efficient because you are not having to create an object for first name and last name at each iteration.

Alternatively you could just create a new column called full_name:

```
df1['full_name'] = df1['first_name'] + " " + df1['last_name']
```

and do what you want with that.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do this pretty easily with pylightxl if all you ate doing is reading the data.

```
import pylightxl as xl

db = xl.readxl(‘excelfile.xlsx’)

list_of_fullnames = list(zip(db.ws(‘Sheet1’).col(1), db.ws(‘Sheet1’).col(2)))

for fullname in list_of_fullnames:
    print(fullname)
```